# Android:Image button not working

Tags: android

I am using buttons with images in my app, the issue I am facing is that the layout in android studio shows the image in buttons but when the app is executed in the images aren't present on the button.

**Button Code**

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/button_intro"
       android:layout_width="70dp"
       android:layout_height="70dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
       android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
       android:background="@drawable/round_button"
       android:foreground="@drawable/ic_into"
       app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button_condition"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.634" />
```

**Round Button**

```
<solid
    android:color="@color/colorPrimary">
</solid>
<size
    android:width="120dp"
    android:height="120dp">
</size>
```

Comment: Show the code where you are adding image to the button?

Comment: android:foreground="@drawable/ic_into"

Comment: Where is your drawable placed? I once run into the problem that adding images into drawable-anydpi wont work while on device

Comment: Why dont you use an imageButton widget instead of setting the foreground?

Comment: have you tried ImageButton instead?

Comment: Tried it not working. The images do get appeared in the emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ImageButton, then use android:background to set the image

Comment: Tried it not working. The images do get appeared in the emulator.